# Custom Collection View Cells Showing the wrong image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have about 80 images in my bundle resources. As part of my Category Class I have a property called Image Name which hold the name of the image that I need to load into the image view. I use [UIImage imageNamed:Category.imageName]. This loads the correct image in the custom table cells but not in the collection view cell.

Table View - cell for row at index path

```
NSLog(@"Index = %d",indexPath.row);
CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
if(cell == nil){
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
Category *current = [self.editCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
[[cell itemTitle]setText:current.title];
cell.backgroundColor = current.categoryColor;
cell.itemImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:current.imageName];

return cell;
```

Collection View - Cell for row at index path …

```
NSArray *catagoriesPulled = [[CategoryStore categoryStore]allCatagories];
Category *categoryRequested = [catagoriesPulled objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
CustomCollectionViewCell *cell = (CustomCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CustomCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell setController:self];
cell.categoryImageView.image = nil;
cell.categoryTitle.numberOfLines = 1;
cell.categoryTitle.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
[[cell categoryTitle]setText:categoryRequested.title];
cell.categoryImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:categoryRequested.imageName];
NSLog(@"%@,%@",categoryRequested.title, categoryRequested.imageName);
cell.backgroundColor = categoryRequested.categoryColor;
return cell;
```

When I run the application on the simulator, it works perfectly but on an actual device, the collection view cell's image view loads random images from the 80 included but the table view loads the correct one.

Any help would be useful. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

When you created the custom cell, you may have changed the default name of the imageview... thats ok but make sure that you link it in the outlets section on the xib file. (click your xib file, then click the custom cell then look to make sure its linked)

edit:
based on your comment, it almost sounds like this is an issue where you have to do a clean on the app (product->clean) also delete the app from the phone or simulator. then rebuild and the new image will show up. this can happen when you change the image to another image but keep the same file name. The file can be cached on the device sometimes.

Comment: Yes, I am sure that I added it. I tried using different ways of accessing the image, image named or nsbundle main bundle but it still shows up with a different picture

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the correct names of images when you do:
`NSLog(@"%@,%@",categoryRequested.title, categoryRequested.imageName);` ?

You might want to check that you don't have a retain cycle in your `CustomCollectionView` with `[cell setController:]`. This usually causes some weird stuff to happen (especially on devices with lower memory, I've found). You might have extra instances of these cells and their subviews being retained, which may be what is causing the wrong images to appear.

Comment: I cycled through the log, the correct image names are linked to each category and I don't use a retain statement anywhere. Thanks a ton anyways.

Comment: You actually don't have to use `[myObject retain]` to have a retain cycle. Does this still happen if you remove `[cell setController:self]`?

Comment: What I meant is that I think there is a "Class A retains class B which retains class A" thing going on here where self retains each tableViewCell and each tableViewCell retains self. [here is a good article explaining this.](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/rules-to-avoid-retain-cycles.html)